# ¿Cómo puedo crear un lanzador en el escritorio de Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Quisiera saber cómo crear un 'lanzador' en el escritorio de ubuntu 16.04 para que corra el comando python3, sin tener que abrir la terminal.

Estuve creando un archivo python.desktop y le coloqué:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Python 3
Comment=BASH PYTHON
Exec=/usr/bin/python
Terminal=python3
Type=Application
```

sin embargo, me da un error:

> ```
> No se encontró el archivo de escritorio
> ```

Comment: Hola Dario, ¿Cual es el problema que te da exactamente?

Comment: No se encontró el archivo de escritorio dice

Answer (score 0):

Si el comando `/usr/bin/python3` no funciona, intenta utilizar `/usr/bin/python`, aunque es probable que al utilizar este último se ejecute python2.

También puedes agregar el valor Icon (por ejemplo: `Icon=/home/usuario/python.png`)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Python 3
Comment=BASH PYTHON
Exec=/usr/bin/python3
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```